# Using retina.js and LESS does this slow down my website

Tags: javascript, less, retina.js

I'm using retina.js and LESS on the website and we're seeing a significant delay in page loading on IPADS. Does retina.js slow down page loading?

Comment: By nature of loading new images, I'd say yes, it slows down page loading. From what I remember seeing about retina.js, it requests higher resolution images if the device is capable...which means more HTTP requests

Comment: can you inject the retina.js script 100ms after domReady? that should fix the page-loading stall and still give the benefits. if retina is done right, there should not be a flash of content swapping when it kicks-in, but even if there is a little jerkiness for an instant, i'd rather have that than a slow loading page.

Answer (score 2):

As far as LESS goes, if you're processing it server-side, it may be causing some slowdown while the stylesheet generates and gets applied. Typically, I would recommend against compiling server-side for that exact reason. Compile your LESS sheets during development and put the minified CSS files on the server only.

As for retina.js, it's likely it could be slowing down your site for the reasons Ian mentioned above. From the [retina.js website](http://retinajs.com/):

> "When your users load a page, retina.js checks each image on the page to see if there is a high-resolution version of that image on your server. If a high-resolution variant exists, the script will swap in that image in-place.

The way I see it, this means that the script is checking the server once for every image on the page. If you have a shoddy WiFi or cell connection, this could impact the render time on the page, since there's an extra HTTP request for every image. ([Extra HTTP requests are bad](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html), by the way.)

You should also review the overall size of your Retina images. If the file size is large, it will take longer to download and render.